# implicit extension methods on type refinements

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, refinement-type

I seem to be unable to get implicit extension methods to work with type refinements, in scala 2.12.4. Consider the following:

```
trait MyTypeclass[A,B] {
  def foo[C](a : Test.Aux[A,B], c : C ) : Test.Aux[A,C]
}

object MyTypeclass {
  trait Ops[A,B] {
    def instance : MyTypeclass[A,B]
    def self : Test.Aux[A,B]
    def foo[C](c : C) : Test.Aux[A,C] = instance.foo[C](self,c)
  }

  object syntax {
    def toAllOps[A,B](t : Test.Aux[A,B])(implicit tc : MyTypeclass[A,B]) = new Ops[A,B] {
      val instance = tc
      val self = t
    }
  }
}

trait Test[A] {
  type B
}

object Test {

  type Aux[A,B0] = Test[A] { type B = B0 }

  def apply[A,B0] : Aux[A,B0] = new Test[A] { type B = B0 } 

  implicit def instance[A,B] : MyTypeclass[A,B] = new MyTypeclass[A,B] { 
    /** Does nothing more than change the second type `B` to the passed value `C` */
    def foo[C](a : Test.Aux[A,B], c : C) : Test.Aux[A,C] = new Test[A] { type B = C }
  }

  import MyTypeclass.syntax.toAllOps
  toAllOps(Test[String,Int]).foo(2.0)
  //Test[String,Int].foo(2.0) // ERROR : `foo is not a member of Test.Aux[String,Int]`
}
```

The penultimate line works fine, but the last line doesn't. The compiler for some reason is unable to link up the typeclass extension methods with the `Aux`.

Can somebody explain why this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `toAllOps` is not implicit.

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid I will have to remove this question due to my carelesness ... Duh!

Comment: Wouldn't be too bad if the people who upvoted also voted to close with reason "Off-topic -> trivial typographical error"; Just an aside: there is also [this cool & quite rare badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) (it just popped into my head for some reason :P )